# Rails - How does the show and new action work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Very general question I was hoping someone could clarify for me. I'm looking at the basic generated scaffold code for a model called products. I noticed the new and show actions in the controller don't have much written in them. In fact, show is entirely empty and new only has the line "`@product = Product.new`". I know these 2 actions are supposed to go to a separate view. A view to show the resource, and a new form view to input info and create a resource, respectively.

So, I'm curious how that actually happens. Other actions have redirect_to :some_path which makes sense, but how exactly does "`render action 'show', location: @product` " bring up the items show page when the action is empty? Also how is that different from `redirect_to @product` ?

thanks

Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render produces a string that will displayed as the response to the request to the application.

redirect_to produces a response header resulting in a new request to the application.

The `render action 'show', location: @product` uses the the file `app/views/products/show.html.erb` with `@product` as a parameter to produce the html which will be returned.

The reason some of the controller functions are empty is that rails are using defaults. So if you don't tell rails what to render then rails will look for a file in the appropriate location.

Methods ending with `redirect_to` are usually post/patch requests saving something in your database and after the requested action has been performed they redirect the user to a method meant for displaying information.

Comment: Ah i see. One last thing. I know that respond_to do |format| decides what format the request is asking for and I understand something like "format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }" but what about             " "format.json { head :no_content }" Wouldn't you want those two choices to do the same thing?

Comment: Not necessarily. Usually json requests (in my experience) are made through ajax from javascript. Such a front end is usually quite intelligent and can decide what to do for it self. I would probably send an "Everything ok". If you force them to do the same thing your show action will have to be able to handle the json requests as well.